# Android: How to set custom keyboard for app?

Tags: android, input, keyboard

A good example for what I'm looking for is the custom keyboard used by the WolframAlpha app.

Ideally I would like to set a custom keyboard for each EditText (one that only shows certain characters/digits), although I'm not certain that this is possible.

If anyone can point me in the direction of examples for how to do this and/or provide assistance in any other manner, it would be greatly appreciated.

I have been unable, so far, to find an example using Google of what I need to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: If you write a good answer I will accept it regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For developing custom keypad you should check this

android official [docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html) and this [sample app](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html)

and may this [**tutorial**](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html) help you

Comment: Isn't this a system wide implementation?

Answer (score 0):

See [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)'s [android:imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions) and [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) to tell the keyboard what type of keyboard you want and if you want an enter key or something else (like "Go").

Comment: But I mean a keyboard where you specify the letter/number positions and so forth.  I thought this is possible in XML, but I'm not sure.  I am also trying to do this without using a full system standard keyboard.

Comment: not possible as much as I know, unless you want to implement your own keyboard app. what keyboard does Wolfram Alpha show?

Comment: It has its own style keyboard with various functions and such, but it isn't installed into your system and it isn't applied as a system-wide keyboard.  I'll add a screenshot to the OP.